# Cakephp key visible in index list but not value for linked table

Tags: cakephp

To make it clearer (changed after first two comments below)...

Councils Controller for index, the problem is that the numeric 'region_id' is displayed on the index view instead of the linked 'region->name'.

```
    function index() {
    $this->Council->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('councils', $this->paginate());
}
```

Councils Model:

```
    var $belongsTo = array(
    'Region' => array(
        'className' => 'Region',
        'foreignKey' => 'region_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);

var $hasMany = array(
    'Person' => array(
        'className' => 'Person',
        'foreignKey' => 'council_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )
);
```

SQL

```
--
-- Table structure for table `councils`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `councils` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
`email` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`website` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`websource` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`region_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=17 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `regions`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `regions` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=20 ;
```

Comment: This depends on your model associations for `Region` and `Council` as well as the `recursive` option for your `find()` or `read()` call. You should post that instead of your schema.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the list of regions to the view correctly, but you need to make sure that your relationship between the two models are set up correctly.  In your Council model, make sure that you have the following:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Region' => array(
        'className' => 'Region',
        'foreignKey' => 'region_id'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your index function to:

```
function index() {
    $this->Council->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('councils', $this->paginate());
    $regions = $this->Council->Region->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('regions'));
}
```

No all you have to do is reference the regions array in the view:

```
echo $regions[$councils['Council']['region_id']];
```

This will display the `Name` instead of `region_id`.

One other thing, make sure you have the $hasMany relationship set in the Region Model too.

Comment: Doh! Thanks for bringing that to my attention.

Comment: I've updated my question, sorry wasn't very understandable - hope it is now... ;-)